# lex pattern to match ipv4 dotted decimal notation

Tags: c++, c, token, lex, flex-lexer

I have a pattern that is given below to match an ipv4 address in the dotted decimal notation.

```
IPV4ADDRESS (([[:digit:]]{1,3}"."){3}([[:digit:]]{1,3}))
```

and I use

```
%x S_rule S_dst_ip

<S_rule>(dst-ip){SPACE}   {

           BEGIN(S_dst_ip);

        }


<S_dst_ip>\{{IPV4ADDRESS}\}  {

       /*code to process the sring here.*/
     }
```

to match an input of the form

```
dst-ip {10.13.12.138}
```

Now I want to match

```
dst-ip { 10.13.12.138 } in addition to dst-ip {10.13.12.138}
```

I modify the IPV4ADDRESS defined above as follows

```
IPV4ADDRESS [ \t]*(([[:digit:]]{1,3}"."){3}([[:digit:]]{1,3}))[ \t]*
```

However this modification doesn't seem to match

```
  dst-ip { 10.13.12.138 } OR dst-ip {10.13.12.138}
```

Can someone point out the error in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it 'works for me', I can't tell you what's wrong with your code as you've not shown an SSCCE  ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Here's one:

```
/*IPV4ADDRESS     (([[:digit:]]{1,3}"."){3}([[:digit:]]{1,3}))*/
IPV4ADDRESS [ \t]*(([[:digit:]]{1,3}"."){3}([[:digit:]]{1,3}))[ \t]*
SPACE [ \t]

%x S_rule S_dst_ip

%%

%{
    BEGIN S_rule;
%}

<S_rule>(dst-ip){SPACE}   {
           BEGIN(S_dst_ip);
        }

<S_dst_ip>\{{IPV4ADDRESS}\}  {
       printf("\n\nMATCH [%s]\n\n", yytext);
       BEGIN S_rule;
     }

. { ECHO; }

%%

int main(void)
{
    while (yylex() != 0)
        ;
    return(0);
}

int yywrap(void)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Using a test data file based on text from your question:

```
dst-ip {10.13.12.138}
dst-ip { 10.13.12.138 } 
dst-ip {10.13.12.138}
dst-ip { 10.13.12.138 } OR dst-ip {10.13.12.138}
```

The program above produces (some blank lines elided):

```
MATCH [{10.13.12.138}]

MATCH [{ 10.13.12.138 }]

MATCH [{10.13.12.138}]

MATCH [{ 10.13.12.138 }]

 OR 

MATCH [{10.13.12.138}]
```

If I had to guess what's going wrong, I'd suspect that you're missing the switch back to state `S_rule` after recognizing `S_dst_ip` (and possibly the opening `%{ BEGIN S_rule; %}` phrase too).

I note in passing that this will accept `{999.999.999.999}` as an IPv4 address.  However, it's feasible to fix that with a more tightly controlled expression, and isn't germane to your main problem.